# Update calculatable fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sum, sql-update

So I have 2 tables.

projects

```
  id: Integer, PK
  rating: Float
```

project_counters

```
  project_id: Integer
  expires_at: DateTime
  value: Float
```

Is there a way to write a query that will update all the `projects` records setting the rating to the sum of values on corresponding counters which have `expires_at` set in the future?

Comment: Well, what's in the "future" changes every second :-) You better calculate that in a view...

Comment: @dnoeth I don't really care for that kind of precision here. half a day will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with a correlated subquery :

```
UPDATE projects p
SET p.rating = (
    SELECT SUM(pc.value)
    FROM projects_counter pc
    WHERE 
        pc.project_id = p.id
        AND pc.expires_at > NOW()
);
```

Comment: And is there a way to fill i with 0 when there are no live counters?

Comment: I mean apart from running a second query updating everything with `rating IS NULL` to 0.

Answer (score 1):

@GMB's answer should do the trick, but it's worth also considering another approach - why even bother saving this rating to the `projects` table, when you could just calculate it on the fly with a query at will:

```
SELECT   project_id, SUM(value)
FROM     projects_counter
WHERE    expires_at > NOW()
GROUP BY project_id
```

Comment: Because sorting and searching by that value on a regular basis would be harder than just recalculating it couple times a day.